# Iterating through a large array filling it with identically sized, but different, smaller arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large array full of zeros simply defined by:

```
BigArray = np.zeros((100,1000,1000),np.float16)
```

I then have a 3D volume that I randomly rotate outside of python and each time it is rotated I want to import the file into python and add it to the next bit of the array. I currently have the following code that will do it:

```
n = 0

while n < 99:
    Zaxisangle = randint(0,360)
    Yaxisangle = randint(0,360)
    Xaxisangle = randint(0,360)

    os.system('rotatevol -angles {},{},{} -input {} -output {}'.format(Zaxisangle, Yaxisangle, Xaxisangle,
                                                                   MRCfilewithextension, MRCforoutput))
    particledata = mrcopen(MRCforoutput)



    if n < 10:
        ArtTomo[:, 0:100, (100*(n+1))-100:100*(n+1)] = particledata
        n = n+1
    else:
        n = n+1
```

For the purpose of this example we can simplify it down to the following:

```
BigArray = np.zeros((100,1000,1000),np.float16)
particledata = np.random.rand(100,100,100)
n = 0
while n < 99:
    if n < 10:
        ArtTomo[:, 0:100, (100*(n+1))-100:100*(n+1)] = particledata
        n = n+1
    elif: 10 < n < 20
        ArtTomo[:, 100:200, (100*(n+1))-100:100*(n+1)] = particledata
        n = n+1
    else:
        n = n+1
```

I would then write lots of elif statements for each 'row'. Because I am iterating through the array with different files I can't simply fill it with a 'in range(0,1000,100)' statement annoyingly.

whilst I can write out all the elif statements I feel as if there must be a more efficient way to write this code I am just not good enough to see it. Could anyone else write this in a nicer way or am I just going to have to write 10 elif statments (i just don't feel like it is neat code!).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think what you are writing could just be expressed like:

```
BigArray = np.zeros((100,1000,1000),np.float16)
particledata = np.random.rand(100,100,100)
n = 0
while n < 99:
    start = 100 * (n // 10)
    ArtTomo[:, start:start+100, (100*(n+1))-100:100*(n+1)] = particledata
    n = n+1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Error putting a 100,100,100 array into 100,0,0 array although I cannot understand why erroring doing this at n = 5 with your code.

Comment: If a dimension of the target is `0` it means the slice stop is the same as the start, or smaller.  Sounds like this is just a bookkeeping error, making sure that the slice numbers are correct at all iterations.